# TabHost bar is above the keyboard when input data in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, keyboard, android-tabhost

In my app I use the tabhost to create a menu bar like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/realtabcontent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <TabWidget
        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:orientation="horizontal" />
</LinearLayout>
```

And

```
 tabHost = (FragmentTabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
        tabHost.setup(this, getSupportFragmentManager(), R.id.realtabcontent);

        tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("home").setIndicator("Home"),HomeFragment.class, null);
        tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("attraction").setIndicator("Attraction"),AttractionFragment.class, null);
        tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("schedule").setIndicator("Schedule"),ScheduleFragment.class, null);
        tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("map").setIndicator("Map"),MapViewFragment.class, null);
        tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("weather").setIndicator("Weather"),WeatherFragment.class, null);
```

[image]

The problem is , when the keyboard is show , the tabbar is above the keyboard , I have set the input mode like that:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"
```

[image]

**How to hide the tabbar when keyboard shows? Thanks**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**onConfigurationChanged** method can be overridden to handle run-time changes you can use **tabHost.setVisibility( View.GONE );**
[Handling Runtime Change](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html#HandlingTheChange)

```
// from the link above
 @Override
 public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
// Checks whether a hardware keyboard is available
  if (newConfig.hardKeyboardHidden == Configuration.HARDKEYBOARDHIDDEN_NO) {
      tabHost.setVisibility( View.GONE );       

   } 
  else if (newConfig.hardKeyboardHidden ==Configuration.HARDKEYBOARDHIDDEN_YES) {
      tabHost.setVisibility( View.VISIBLE );
   }
  }
```

you can add this piece of code on each activity where you want to hide the tabhost,you just need to pass the Rootview id of your layout.

```
public final int SOFTKEYBOARDHEIGHT=100;
final View activityRootView = findViewById(R.id.YOURROOTVIEW);
activityRootView.getViewTreeObserver()
.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
        int heightDiff = activityRootView.getRootView().getHeight() - activityRootView.getHeight();
        if (heightDiff > SOFTKEYBOARDHEIGHT) { 
            tabHost.setVisibility( View.GONE );  
        }
     }
});
```

Comment: Thanks. That works fine except when I choose photo from album / use camera , after the result return  and I open the input box , the tab bar still show

Comment: the behavior is quite strange.  one keyboard can hide tab bar, when I change tab and open the keyboard in other input , it show the tab bar

Comment: hi there, i have added the getViewTreeObserver listener in order to detect when keyboard is enabled on your activity so you can hide the tabhost when softkeyboard is enabled on the screen

Comment: android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" please add this under each activity where you want to enable the above listener.

Comment: also is it I need to put android:configChanges="keyboard"  in the application in mainfest .xml?  thanks

Comment: yes mate,also add this one android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize"

Comment: last question. try final View activityRootView = findViewById(R.id.realtabcontent) but seems not working, try log the diff but when keyboard show/ hide the diff has not changed . Thanks for helping

Comment: you must give your parent linear view an id and after that use that view as your parent view,and not use R.id.realtabcontent.

Comment: second solution work for me! thank lot!  Caution, don't add android:windowSoftInputMode in AndroidManifest